# swift + firebase, ios 14 - SIGABRT dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I am developing an iOS app and wanted to integrate a app clip into the app... my app uses firestore and fireauth... I added a new app clip, added it to my provisioning profile, and it builds and runs, however moments after the build loads onto a device or simulator I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/App/D33062EE-75AE-452D-BB66-26D8092BB36D/App.app/AppClip
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
```

I have tried everything, disintegrating and reintegrating my pods, using "use_modular_headers!" (which doesn't work with swift ive learned), and I even tried to recreate the entire app in a new project...the app itself runs fine as its own standalone ios target, but once it is in an app clip it all falls apart. My app clip podfile and podfile.lock are below, is there something I'm doing wrong, or is this a firebase or ios/xcode issue?

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
end

target 'AppClip' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for AppClip
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
    end
  end
end




PODS:
  - abseil/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/algorithm/container (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/algorithm/algorithm (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/algorithm/container (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/base_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/bits (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/config (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/core_headers (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/endian (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/errno_saver (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/log_severity (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/malloc_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/pretty_function (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/atomic_hook (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/base (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/log_severity
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/spinlock_wait
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/base_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/base/bits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/config (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/core_headers (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/endian (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/errno_saver (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/base/exponential_biased (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/log_severity (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/base/malloc_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/dynamic_annotations
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/base/periodic_sampler (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/exponential_biased
  - abseil/base/pretty_function (0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/atomic_hook
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/log_severity
  - abseil/base/spinlock_wait (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/errno_saver
  - abseil/base/throw_delegate (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/container/compressed_tuple (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal
    - abseil/memory/memory
  - abseil/container/inlined_vector_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/container/compressed_tuple
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/memory/memory (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/meta (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/meta/type_traits (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/meta/type_traits (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/numeric/int128 (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
  - abseil/strings/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/strings/str_format (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/strings/str_format_internal
  - abseil/strings/str_format_internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/types/span
  - abseil/strings/strings (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/bits
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/endian
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/internal
  - abseil/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/time (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
  - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
  - abseil/time/time (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
    - abseil/numeric/int128
    - abseil/strings/strings
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/civil_time
    - abseil/time/internal/cctz/time_zone
  - abseil/types (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/types/any (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/compare (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/span (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/variant (= 0.20200225.0)
  - abseil/types/any (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl
  - abseil/types/bad_any_cast_impl (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_optional_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/bad_variant_access (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/raw_logging_internal
  - abseil/types/compare (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/optional (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/memory/memory
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_optional_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/types/span (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/algorithm/algorithm
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/base/throw_delegate
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - abseil/types/variant (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/base/core_headers
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
    - abseil/types/bad_variant_access
    - abseil/utility/utility
  - abseil/utility/utility (0.20200225.0):
    - abseil/base/base_internal
    - abseil/base/config
    - abseil/meta/type_traits
  - BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (= 0.0.7)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Implementation (0.0.7):
    - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (= 0.0.7)
  - BoringSSL-GRPC/Interface (0.0.7)
  - Firebase (6.30.0):
    - Firebase/Core (= 6.30.0)
  - Firebase/Auth (6.30.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAuth (~> 6.8.0)
  - Firebase/Core (6.30.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.7.2)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.30.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.10.0)
  - Firebase/Firestore (6.30.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.16.4)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.7.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.8)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.4)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.7.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseAuth (6.8.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.10)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (~> 1.1)
  - FirebaseCore (6.10.0):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.3)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.7)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.5.0):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 7.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.7)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseFirestore (1.16.4):
    - abseil/algorithm (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/base (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/meta (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/time (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types (= 0.20200225.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.10)
    - "gRPC-C++ (~> 1.28.0)"
    - leveldb-library (~> 1.22)
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - FirebaseFirestoreSwift (0.3.0):
    - FirebaseFirestore (>= 1.6.1, ~> 1.6)
  - FirebaseInstallations (1.6.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.10)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.7)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.7)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.7)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.7)"
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleDataTransport (7.2.0):
    - nanopb (~> 1.30905.0)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.7.2):
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.7.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.7.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - "gRPC-C++ (1.28.2)":
    - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (= 1.28.2)"
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
  - "gRPC-C++/Implementation (1.28.2)":
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - "gRPC-C++/Interface (= 1.28.2)"
    - gRPC-Core (= 1.28.2)
  - "gRPC-C++/Interface (1.28.2)"
  - gRPC-Core (1.28.2):
    - gRPC-Core/Implementation (= 1.28.2)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Implementation (1.28.2):
    - abseil/container/inlined_vector (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/memory/memory (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/str_format (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/strings/strings (= 0.20200225.0)
    - abseil/types/optional (= 0.20200225.0)
    - BoringSSL-GRPC (= 0.0.7)
    - gRPC-Core/Interface (= 1.28.2)
  - gRPC-Core/Interface (1.28.2)
  - GTMSessionFetcher/Core (1.4.0)
  - IQKeyboardManagerSwift (6.5.6)
  - leveldb-library (1.22)
  - nanopb (1.30905.0):
    - nanopb/decode (= 1.30905.0)
    - nanopb/encode (= 1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/decode (1.30905.0)
  - nanopb/encode (1.30905.0)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.10)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase
  - Firebase/Auth
  - Firebase/Firestore
  - FirebaseFirestoreSwift
  - IQKeyboardManagerSwift

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - abseil
    - BoringSSL-GRPC
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseAuth
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseFirestore
    - FirebaseFirestoreSwift
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleUtilities
    - "gRPC-C++"
    - gRPC-Core
    - GTMSessionFetcher
    - IQKeyboardManagerSwift
    - leveldb-library
    - nanopb
    - PromisesObjC

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  abseil: 6c8eb7892aefa08d929b39f9bb108e5367e3228f
  BoringSSL-GRPC: 8edf627ee524575e2f8d19d56f068b448eea3879
  Firebase: 210f41ca352067d83b1ba4fd2e7fb49a0c017397
  FirebaseAnalytics: a299a86ef70fcc6aa011418bc65a7e101fb9636c
  FirebaseAuth: 300433de340c1b058dbb8aec224a3f1bcfda5184
  FirebaseCore: 9a41e2de78fef10f63cee30ab10e2945266bc1fc
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 7535fe695737f8c5b350584292a70b7f8ff0357b
  FirebaseFirestore: ff82cd15f8ed3b417c307eb729e3e2e68aad0bdd
  FirebaseFirestoreSwift: 0cda93628782ca5a817cfecd2a8c0187436c0ae5
  FirebaseInstallations: 45f9d44d3a8d6f780fa337ee8987dad87210fcbc
  GoogleAppMeasurement: 3def7652b1f5b5a576178dc332e2a36a260fbef6
  GoogleDataTransport: 672fb0ce96fe7f7f31d43672fca62ad2c9c86f7b
  GoogleUtilities: 7f2f5a07f888cdb145101d6042bc4422f57e70b3
  "gRPC-C++": 13d8ccef97d5c3c441b7e3c529ef28ebee86fad2
  gRPC-Core: 4afa11bfbedf7cdecd04de535a9e046893404ed5
  GTMSessionFetcher: 6f5c8abbab8a9bce4bb3f057e317728ec6182b10
  IQKeyboardManagerSwift: c7df9d2deb356c04522f5c4b7b6e4ce4d8ed94fe
  leveldb-library: 55d93ee664b4007aac644a782d11da33fba316f7
  nanopb: c43f40fadfe79e8b8db116583945847910cbabc9
  PromisesObjC: b14b1c6b68e306650688599de8a45e49fae81151

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 8d4f83eff696268369ccbfe0de051280f065864a

COCOAPODS: 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Firebase (and other networking pods), there is an issue with app clips not supporting http sockets connections, and this is an issue the google api team is dealing with right now:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6211

For other pods that won't load, make sure you have your pods listed in the podfile for both the main app and app clip, and if it still crashes when run, it is because the last phase of the build phases does not include copying the podfiles like in the regular app...

so, go to the project settings, go to your main app, and click on "build phases", then look for "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks"...now, click on your app clip and click the + button in the upper left corner, and choose "new run script phase" and rename is "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks", then copy each string from the original, updating the path to the path of your app clip specifically. Once this is done, the app should run on your simulator or device.

Comment: Also worth noting, the input/output files in the app clip need to be made, if your pods are the same you can use the same paths. If they differ, duplicate the ones from the main app and add/remove the ones you are using/not using, then point to that file in the build phase.